# requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support

Tags: vimscript-python

I compiled vim8.1 with the following options :

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 18 2018 09:50:18)
Included patches: 1-320
Compiled by mohsen@ns1
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       -terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               +perl              +vartabs
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +writebackup
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +xim
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xpm
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/vim8/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16   -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt    -lruby-2.5 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Now, When I put the following line in my vimrc, I get error.

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support.
```

I compiled with python,

The line of `vimrc`:

```
Bundle 'YouCompleteMe'
```

**Where's my problem?**
My vimrc is :

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Bundle 'YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'command-t'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
filetype plugin on
set splitbelow
set splitright
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99
nnoremap <space> za

let g:SimpylFold_docstring_preview=1
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2
    \ set softtabstop=2
    \ set shiftwidth=2
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h "match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: you need a python 2 or 3 library that Vim will load when accessing python api commands. Check the output of `python3 import sys; print(sys.version)` or `python import sys; print sys.version` (note, most likely you won't be able to run both commands in the same session). Also you might check `:set pyhondll? pythonthreedll? pythonhome?` after running the previous command

Comment: You didn't compile with python support.  You compiled with _dynamic_ python support.  You still need to install the shared python library for your system (e.g. `libpython3`).

Comment: **SOLVED:** I removed config dir from `./configure` and added `--with-python-command=/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @PersianGulf Since you solved your problem, please answer your question with an explanation of what the problem was and how you solved it so that future users can easily reproduce your solution. Also don't forget to mark your answer as accepted when you can.

Comment: @PersianGulf please note, that you can't use simutaniously in a single process both Python libraries, reasons of which are well described in `:help python` page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to run `./configure`, You have 3 options for python:

```
--enable-pythoninterp=yes
--with-python-command=/usr/bin/python
--with-python-config-dir=
```

last parameter is deprecated, You have to don't use `--with-python-config-dir` then recompile and reinstall `vim`, After reinstall, You can test via `:echo has("python")`, if it return 1, it means true.
**Note:**
You have the following options for python 3:

```
--enable-python3interp=yes
--with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3
--with-python3-config-dir=
```