# configure VIM with Python support for Debian 9.4 VM Instance

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, vimscript-python

I'm trying to configure VIM with Python support in order to use the You Complete Me pluggin.

This question has been asked before. Unfortunately none of the answers have worked for me. Any suggestions or insights would be great.

I'm running a Google VM Instance, Debian 9.4

My first step was to clone the repo for vim, cd into it, and run this

`./configure --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu`

Then run `make` followed by `sudo make install`

I've tried setting this configuration 30 different ways and every time it's done installing and I run `vim --version` I still get `-python -python3`

I'm aware that you cannot have python and python3, I've tried both of them. So far nothing has worked.

Comment: some other options I tried: `./configure --enable-python3interp=yes / --with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3` and countless variations in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me

`./configure --enable-python3interp / --with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3`

Between this [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17455/20122) and a suggested answer which has since been deleted, I cleaned and redid it, and it finally worked. Now running `vim --version` shows `+python3`.